# How to simplify with XOR after using Quine–McCluskey's Algorithm?

Tags: python, parsing, xor, simplify, boolean-algebra

For my program, I need to simplify boolean expressions, and I can do this using Quine–McCluskey's algorithm, however the end result only contains NOTs, ANDs, and ORs, but no XORs, and the involvement of XORs is crucial for my program - if the result derived from the algorithm contained an expression that can be converted into an XOR, how would I go about doing that?

Thank you.

Comment: To make sure I understand what you’re saying - is your goal to convert an expression made just of AND, NOT, and OR into something as simplified as possible by introducing the XOR connective?

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
def xor(x,y):
    return(not (y and x) and not (not(y or x)))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you, but that does not answer my question. I have updated it now.